# Flutter tag mismatch pronlem

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I just have problem after launching:

```
        Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
        Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
        Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
        Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3454)
        Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
            at com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:592)
            
        Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

There's a lot more log text, just to make it look clearer I left less more text

Comment: have you taken internet use permission?

Comment: anything on Internet doesn't help me, so I just simply reinstalled Windows /_ /